# Graph API Security Alerts properties blank or GUID

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, sentinel

When calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts via python the properties returned do not reflect what is in the documentation. I.e : Category (per docs) = category  String  Category of the alert (for example, credentialTheft, ransomware, etc.).

I'm getting a GUID for category. Other properties like incidentIds are blank...

```
      "id": "redacted",
      "azureTenantId": "redacted",
      "azureSubscriptionId": "redacted",
      "riskScore": null,
      "tags": [],
      "activityGroupName": null,
      "assignedTo": null,
      "category": "e573729c-f65f-46cc-b31b-f5ad7c32ff59_aa5de612-30f2-4e66-8a7f-da99b946ce54",
      "closedDateTime": null,
      "comments": [],
      "confidence": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2020-10-18T18:54:41.9442907Z",
      "description": "Identifies when a rare Resource and ResourceGroup deployment occurs by a previously unseen Caller.",
      "detectionIds": [],
      "eventDateTime": "2020-10-04T18:49:39.9931844Z",
      "feedback": null,
      "incidentIds": [],
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-10-18T18:54:42.0552251Z",
      "recommendedActions": [],
      "severity": "low",
      "sourceMaterials": [],
      "status": "newAlert",
      "title": "Suspicious Resource deployment",
      "vendorInformation": {
        "provider": "Azure Sentinel",
        "providerVersion": null,
        "subProvider": null,
        "vendor": "Microsoft"
      },
      "cloudAppStates": [],
      "fileStates": [],
      "hostStates": [],
      "historyStates": [],
      "malwareStates": [],
      "networkConnections": [],
      "processes": [],
      "registryKeyStates": [],
      "securityResources": [],
      "triggers": [],
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: edited. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts

Comment: If you see any issue with these logging, i would see if there is anything you see in the Azure AD portal & its related logs. If not, i would open a support ticket with Microsoft, see if there is an issue or not.